# Prove: $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{(-1)^n(1+n!)}{2^nn!}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n$ be a recursive sequence where $a_1=42$ and for all $n$:

$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{(-1)^n(1+n!)}{2^nn!}$$

After plugging some values of $n$ I can "see" that the sequence is bounded at $(41,42]$

And that for $a_{2n}$ the sequence is increasing and for $a_{2n+1}$ it is decrecasing

I know that I need to show that the sequence is either monotonic decrecasing  $(a_n\geq a_{n+1})$ or monotonic increasing $(a_n\leq a_{n+1})$

I have tried to set $a_{n+1}=a_n=L$ too, but it did not work, how should I approach this?

One way that I know is to look at $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ and to see if it $\leq 1$ or $\geq 1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that
$$a_{N+1}=a_1+\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^n(1+n!)}{2^nn!}=42+
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1/2)^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^N\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$
and as $N\to +\infty$ both series can be easily evaluated: the first one is related to the [power series of $e^x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) and the second one is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Answer (score 5):

First note that
$$a_{N+1}=a_1+\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^n(1+n!)}{2^nn!}$$
and that
$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n(1+n!)}{2^nn!}\right|\sim 2^{-n}$$
as $n\to+\infty$, so that the serie converges absolutely.